# Where can I find ultrasound machine regulations?

Tags: ultrasound, manufacturing, piezo, certification, regulations

Diagnostic ultrasound machines are limited in their output power so that the sound waves don't cavity the microbubbles in the body.

What I want to know is how do manufacturers prove their power output is safe?

The piezo crystals are variable, so just knowing the RF power from the amplifier isn't good enough.  Do they use a hydrophone?

Where do I find the regulations on the test conditions?  Currently I am trying to determine if certain manufacturers are 'cheating' like car makers do with fuel mileage.

Comment: "regulations" are something that *states* do. You'll need to say where you are, most probably (there's little "global" regulation. From the top of my head, that'd be the ITU governing radio bands, some aeronautical standards, some international shipping standards, and the UN Charta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FDA has got a guidance document](https://www.fda.gov/downloads/UCM070911.pdf) for ultrasound systems and probes.  There is also the [IEC 60601-2-37 standard](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/22634) (it can be difficult to read and follow).

The testing is done using one or more of the following methods: hydrophone, schlieren photography, radiated force measurement.

There are companies who specialize in making measurements for the safety certification.  Large equipment manufacturers might have their own testing facilities.